# Dropping rows by index not working, drop blank rows at start of csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[image]

I am using a csv file. The top 3 rows are completely blank.(Its an SAP output file with initial 3 lines blank). I want to remove the top 3 rows using index. I googled and saw you can drop rows using index label.  I tried the below:

```
df.drop('0')
```

The index label I took as 0 since the index showing in df.head() is 0,1 and 2 for top 3 rows and that s what you see in the image too. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: `'0'` is a string. You need `df.drop(0)` -- not `df.drop('0')`, because default index values have a data type of `int` not `string`. This is a critical thing to understand in programming.

Comment: How to drop 0 and 1 and 2

Comment: Use `df.drop([0,1,2])` or you can do `df.iloc[3:]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`drop` returns a new dataframe. So you need to assign the value return from the df.drop(0) to. a new dataframe.

If you plan to make the changes in the dataframe, you need to add param `inplace=True`. Read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

Comment: The issue is that `'0'` is a string. That is why the row is not being dropped.